# How to pull sub, sub objects with Spring WS and JAXB

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm attempting to pull data from a SOAP service that I have no control over. The hierarchy contains ProductOrder -> ShipTo -> Item where there are one or more shipToes and one or more Items per shipto.

Their API uses a mock SQL like query language.  I'm getting stack traces like the following when trying to pull data including the items.  if I exclude item, I'm able to pull the ProductOrders along with ShipTo objects, but items is always an empty list.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]    at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.Application.main(Application.java:39)
>   ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB
>   exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Field
>   order for ShipTo.Item.ItemId does not match the schema definition for
>   record type ProductOrder  at
>   org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:915)
>   ~[spring-oxm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.CustJaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(CustJaxbUnMarshaller.java:37)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(MarshallingUtils.java:62)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$3.extractData(WebServiceTemplate.java:413)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:619)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
>   ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar:2.4.0.RELEASE]     at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.services.ConvioClient.queryInternal(ConvioClient.java:159)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.services.ConvioClient.query(ConvioClient.java:134)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.services.ProductOrderService.getProductOrders(ProductOrderService.java:87)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.services.ConvioService.load(ConvioService.java:82)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   edu.umich.oud.giftformatter.convioexport.Application.lambda$runner$0(Application.java:72)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]    ... 4 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Field order for
>   ShipTo.Item.ItemId does not match the schema definition for record
>   type ProductOrder     ... 17 common frames omitted

The product order service contains a method like so:

```
public List<ProductOrderObj> getProductOrders(final Date startDate, final Date endDate) {
final String query = String.format("SELECT siteId,orderId,transactionId,purchaseAmount,taxDeductibleValue,\n" +
                "shippingCharge,additionalDonation,discountAmount,discountCode,\n" +
                "creationDate,createdBy,modifyDate,lastChangeBy,storeId,payment,\n" +
                "purchaser,interactionSource,shipTo,\n" +
                "receiptNumber,shipTo.item FROM ProductOrder where creationDate > %s and creationDate < %s",
        convertDate(startDate), convertDate(endDate));

log.info("query is " + query);

final Session session = convioClient.startSession();
final ArrayList<ProductOrderObj> events = new ArrayList<>();
for (int page = 1; page < 100; page++) {
    final List<? extends RecordObj> items = convioClient.query(session, page, ConvioConfiguration.MAX_DOWNLOADS_PER_REQUEST, query);
    if (items.size() < ConvioConfiguration.MAX_DOWNLOADS_PER_REQUEST) {
        events.addAll((List<ProductOrderObj>) items);
        break;
    }
    events.addAll((List<ProductOrderObj>) items);
}
return events;
```

}

Which in turn calls the convioService.query method that effectively does this

```
  private List<? extends RecordObj> queryInternal(final Session session, final 
               int page, final int pageSize, final String q) {
    // setup query
    final Query query = new Query();
    query.setPage(BigInteger.valueOf(page));
    query.setPageSize(BigInteger.valueOf(pageSize));
    query.setQueryString(q);
    log.trace(q);

    // perform query
    try {
        final Object obj = getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(query,
                new SoapActionExecutionIdCallback(session));
        final QueryResponse response = (QueryResponse) obj;

        if (response != null) {
            log.debug("Response was a " + response.getClass().getName());
            return response.getRecord();
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    throw new NullPointerException("response was null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be two issues causing this not to work:

1. Bad field definition for the child object. shipTo.items vs shipTo.Items
2. Disabling validation of the dtd in the marshaller/unmarshaller